# when an object of listView is being clicked, which listener you can use?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-intent

when an object of listView is being clicked, which listener you can use?

Comment: setOnItemClickListene

Answer (score 2):

You can use listView setOnItemClick Listener of listview click event.

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
   {
      @Override
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v, int position,
            long arg3) 
      {
            // do what you intend to do on click of listview row
      }
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

@Muhammad Talha: Please clarify your question. What you actually mean by

> object of listView

You need to know about the `ListLiew` item click event then ***Chirag's*** answer is correct. And if you need click event of the object you taken inside your `ListLiew` adapter's row item, then you need to set individual *Click Listener* inside your `Adapter.getView()` method.